# how to recieve exception for deleted event from recurring event in outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-restapi

I am using Outlook push notification API to receive events from the calendar.
When an event is deleted from recurring event, I get a notification with type 'updated'. But I do not get the information of the deleted event. How can I get the information about the deleted event?

Comment: Did you resolve this?